# flush mode changed in grails from AUTO to MANUAL

Tags: hibernate, grails, save, flush

After upgrading my Grails project from 1.3.7 to 2.4.0 and after fixing various issues related to the new grails version, I realized that none of the changes done to any object would be persisted anymore (at all) except if `save(flush:true)` is called.

With Grails 1.3.7 the default behavior when saving a domain instance using `save()` is that changes get persisted automatically, due to hibernate flushMode => `FlushMode.AUTO`. In Grails 2.4.0 this is not true anymore. The default flushMode of the hibernate session inside any controller action or service class is `FlushMode.MANUAL`.

Things get even stranger when retrieving `sessionFactory.currentSession.flushMode` in BootStrap, where it has a value of `FlushMode.AUTO` and in a controller action where it has the value `FlushMode.MANUAL`. This can be verified by creating a new grails app and putting `println "flushMode = $sessionFactory.currentSession.flushMode"` in BootStrap and in a controller action (eg. index()).

I have been searching through all kind of forums for the last 2 days and did not find any reasonable explanation why this had to be changed in Grails 2.4.0 (or maybe even in earlier versions). I only found comments saying its kind of risky to have `FlushMode.MANUAL` because you may run into stale objects when querying the db after some others have been modified.

I know that:

- with `grails.gorm.autoFlush = true` in config you can force a flush:true to every save()
- in hibernate3 and hibernate4 default flushMode is `FlushMode.AUTO`
- its not possible to set flushMode in Config.groovy nor in DataSource.groovy. I tried all of this and nothing did the job:
  `hibernate.flush.mode = 'auto'
  hibernate.flushMode = 'auto'
  hibernate.session.flush.mode = 'auto'
  hibernate.session.flushMode = 'auto'
  dataSource.hibernate.flush.mode = 'auto'
  dataSource.hibernate.flushMode = 'auto'
  dataSource.hibernate.session.flush.mode = 'auto'
  dataSource.hibernate.session.flushMode = 'auto'
  dataSource.flush.mode = 'auto'
  dataSource.flushMode = 'auto'
  dataSource.session.flush.mode = 'auto'
  dataSource.session.flushMode = 'auto'`

Please can someone throw a little light in this ?

Actually I would like to know if in Grails 2.4.0 `FlushMode.MANUAL` is now the desired default?

And if so:

- What is with the comment "… The proposal is not that we disable the AUTO flush mode completely …" by Peter Ledbrook in [GRAILS-7180](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7108)
- What is the *best practice* to not run into the problems with stale objects, especially when doing complex manipulations on domain-objects where modifying, creating new instances and querying is all mixed.

Thanks very much
- Andi

---

Upon reading Graemes Answer and his comments, I tried to better clarify what I am struggling with and added the following simplified domain and controller classes which demonstrate that behavior:

Domain class Msg:

```groovy
class Msg {

    String  text

    static constraints = {
        text nullable:true
    }
}
```

and the msg Controller:

```groovy
class MsgController {
    def sessionFactory

    def index = {
        def out = ["*** flushMode when in controller/index = \
                   $sessionFactory.currentSession.flushMode"]
        Msg.list().each { out << "$it.id: text=$it.text" }
        render out.join('<br>')
    }

    // this save does persist the new msg object, 
    // even if flushMode = MANUAL
    def save1 = {
        def out = ["*** flushMode when in controller/save = \
                   $sessionFactory.currentSession.flushMode"]
        def msg = new Msg(text:'hallo')
        if (!msg.save()) {
            out << "msg has errors! " + msg.errors
        }
        out << "msg $msg.id created with text = $msg.text"
        render out.join('<br>')
    }

    // this save does NOT persist the new msg object, even if its valid
    // (difference is calling hasErrors()
    def save2 = {
        def out = ["*** flushMode when in controller/save = \
                   $sessionFactory.currentSession.flushMode"]
        def msg = new Msg(text:'hallo')
        if (msg.hasErrors() && !msg.save()) {
            out << "msg has errors! " + msg.errors
        }
        out << "msg $msg.id created with text = $msg.text"
        render out.join('<br>')
    }
}
```

So calling `http://localhost/appname/msg/save1` the output is:

```
*** flushMode when in controller/save1 = MANUAL
msg 1 created with text = hallo
```

Here I don't get it, why hibernate persists the object, even thou flushMode is MANUAL.

And when calling `http://localhost/appname/msg/save2` the output is:

```
*** flushMode when in controller/save2 = MANUAL
msg null created with text = hallo
```

The object does not get persisted because hibernate does not issue a flush, thus never calls a sql "update ..." command.

But now it seems that not only the flushMode is an issue, but also if one calls hasErrors() or not! I am puzzled even more ...

If you do this example in Grails 1.3.7 both save actions (save1 and save2) do persist the  newly created msg object!

Answer (score 11):

Grails will set the flush mode to Manual prior to validating to prevent any changes being flushed during validation (this can be quite common as you may have a custom validator that queries existing data).

If there are any validation errors it will not set the flush mode back to AUTO. This is to prevent invalid objects being persisted.

You probably have validation errors occurring and although you can force a flush it isn't advisable.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Thats what makes sense. But why does Grails switch to MANUAL in a controller action even if no domain objects are saved (used at all)? I wrote a tiny Grails app with just 1 controller and no domain class to verify that. In the controller index action I only put 1 LOC `println "flushMode = $sessionFactory.currentSession.flushMode"`

Comment: For read operations Grails uses a read-only transaction. A read-only transaction uses a flush mode of MANUAL. The reason read operations use a read-only transaction is because it improves performance as Hibernate has no need to dirty check read only objects. This may be what you are seeing.

Comment: See the original question with updated domain and controller example

Comment: Your second example makes no sense, since doing `if (msg.hasErrors() && !msg.save())` means that `save()` is never called because `hasErrors()` will return `false`

Comment: Sorry, my typo! It should be `if (msg.hasErrors() || !msg.save())` and then both actions do persist the msg object and the entire example above makes no sense! I'll have to review the problematic code and try to extract it to make the problem visible ...

Comment: Well, I nailed it down: Msg domain has a Date property 'begin' too and only this property was not persisted, but the 'text' property was. Enabling logging of hibernate sql statements revealed that. So I had a deeper look at the domain class def. and I saw that I accidentally mapped the 'begin' property using `begin formula: 'begin_date'` instead of `begin column: 'begin_date'`. Well, that did cost me some more grey hair but I learned a little more about flushing in hibernate and grails :-)

Comment: Is it still correct that Grails sets the flush mode to Manual? I was having issues with the session flushing while calling queries during validation and I looked here : https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/9fa9aa17d028bdbc9da3895741f9997dab3e2ba5/grails-datastore-gorm-support/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/validation/DefaultDomainClassValidator.java and noticed that flush mode is being set to Commit not Manual. I am using 2.4.3 however. This was causing issues for me as something was still flushing, so I had to manually set to Manual.