# Grails do not commit after a successful service call

Tags: grails, grails-orm, transactional

I'm performing the following logic on a single `Service` in [grails](/questions/tagged/grails) 2.4.4.

```java
class SampleService {
    void process(params1, params2) {
        SampleDomain1 sd1 = new SampleDomain1()
        sd1.setProperties(params1)
        sd1.save()

        SampleDomain2 sd2 = new SampleDomain2()
        sd2.setProperties(params2)
        sd2.save()
    }
}
```

What I understand is that `Service`s are by default transactional. If `sd1.save()` is successful but `sd2.save()` is not, it will rollback the changes and will throw an error. While if both are successful, both are committed upon service's exit.

If my understanding is correct, then both of it should already been persisted to the database. However, the problem is: it does not— unless if you explicitly use the `flush: true` parameter based on my tests using the same set of `params1` and `params2`.

```java
        sd1.save(flush: true)

        SampleDomain2 sd2 = new SampleDomain2()
        sd2.setProperties(params2)
        sd2.save(flush: true)
    }
```

Which, by the way is what I am really avoiding (what would be the point setting it as `@Transactional`). If that's the catch of Hibernate 4 / Grails 2.4, **what do I need to do to make my services to commit at every end of a service call again**? Do I need to configure any global configuration of Grails? I really need to flush my Domain classes at the end of every service automatically.

---

## Note

I've already assured that the data is correct, including calling `.validate()` and other checker. Success in performing `.save(flush: true)` proves that. The problem I found is [regarding to the update on Grails 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24309084/4043409) on its `FlushMode`. Now, maybe what I really need is a global settings to override this.

Comment: Try adding this: `grails.gorm.failOnError=true` to your `Config.groovy`. This will tell Grails to throw an exception, globally, when an error occurs with GORM persistence.

Comment: Also, flushing Hibernate sessions (ie making your DB up to date with the objects in memory) is not the same as committing a transaction. So, even after flushing, a rollback of the transaction will revert the DB changes. Also, I found it a good practice to do `assert domainObject.save()`, to make sure the object is properly saved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grails services are not transactional?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744509/grails-services-are-not-transactional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere on my `DataSource.groovy` configuration, there is this line:

```
hibernate {
        ...
        singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
        flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
        ^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Which explicit states that every save should be flushed manually. As a solution, I comment out this line. After that, every database transaction now commits every time it exists a `Service`.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is not being flushed to the database layer there are some possibilities that come to mind.

1. There's some kind of error when trying to save to the database, you can try passing failOnError=true parameter to the .save() calls to see it clearly. (Actually setting this globally is a good idea since silently failing db calls are a migraine)
2. You are calling this service method from within the same service object. This will not allow the underlying spring declarative transactions to work due to the use of proxies.
3. You might have annotated some other method in the same service, in which case the default transactional support is no longer available for the remaining un-annotated (is this even a word?) methods.
4. You might have created the Service somewhere outside of service folder, not quite sure if this can cause an issue since I've never tried it out.
5. You have failed to sacrifice a goat to the Groovy and Grails Gods and they are messing with your head.

Edit :
I'm going to try to answer the points in your new edit.

1. Have you tried failOnError? It might be a issue that occurs when both objects are flushed to the DB at once, instead of manually committing them one at a time.
2. By figuring out a way to auto flush on save, you are going to be bypassing the transactions altogether AFAIK, now if I'm wrong then by all means go for it. But do test it out first before assuming.